# Error in Kivy 1.8 upgrade

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a compilation error when upgrading to Kivy 1.8 the error is the following :

```
/tmp/easy_install-toDKWY/Kivy-1.8.0/kivy/graphics/gl_redirect.h:38:22: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
     #   include <GL/gl.h
```

can anyone help?

EDIT : i have solved my problem and wanted to share the solution. The problem was sure not in Kivy but in the installation of it on my platform. what i did is uninstall Kivy and re-install it again using apt-install (on Lunix Ubuntu). Thank you all.

Comment: Well, do you have the GL/gl.h header installed somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: From the error i think that i don't have such file

Comment: Then you probably need to install some sort of OpenGL-dev package, probably using whatever packaging mechanism your distro uses.

Comment: You are right i am trying to install python-opengl package to see if this work... Hopefully?!?

Comment: it did not work either... i still don't know why? i have OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed all the dependencies mentioned here http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html#ubuntu

You could also try out the pre-built packages from here https://launchpad.net/~kivy-team/+archive/kivy
or here http://kivy.org/#download